# What is the best way to handle DateTime in a Web Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datetime

I've been doing some research around on how to properly store and save the Date and Time in a Web Application but I couldn't find a post that has a marked answer.

I have a ASP.NET MVC website and I use C# for backend code and MS SQL for the database, let say you have different client with different TimeZone currently I'm storing the DateTime by DateTime.UtcNow and I just display it back in "YYYY/MM/DD" format.

Answer (score 0):

All you really need to do is make sure the application server and the database server share the same time settings and are in sync.

IIS, .NET, and SQL Server all use the system time by default.

Clients in different time zones will still use the system time of the IIS server they are connected too. Most sites just format the date on the client side, to the clients zone.

If you want to get fancy, you can write database triggers that handle transaction time stamps. This comes in handy if you do a lot of back-end processing.

Comment: so you're saying that as long as the Application Server and the Database server are in sync then I don't to do any changes in my code?

Comment: BTW, I'm using Azure for hosting my application and Database

Comment: @jmaghuyop Yes, this is fairly standard practice. Are you running into a specific issue surrounding time zones?

Comment: @jmaghuyop If you're using Azure, you won't have to change anything.

Comment: so far we are experiencing a time difference in our application, one example is that a customer purchase a product today and I saved the date purchased using DateTime.UTCNOW and when I show it in a report it shows it was being showed as Yesterday.

Comment: @jmaghuyop how are you formatting the date in the report?

Comment: I'm formatting it in "DD MM YYYY HH:MM" because my manager want's it in AU format, and from what I remember he told me that there is at least 8-12hrs difference. so now I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong if you said I'm doing the right thing which is to store the date in UTC.

Comment: @jmaghuyop Using UTC is the most efficient way to store time, you just need to make sure you're presenting it to the user correctly. What does it look like in the database?

Comment: SQL server has its own date-time format. It will convert your UTC time into its own format. Be sure you are pulling it out of the database and formatting it within the report as UTC.

Comment: so in the database after I saved it, it shows "2016-09-07 05:08:54.980" which is 1:09 PM in my Time (Manila Philippines) and it should be around 3 PM but on the reports it shows 05:08:54 AM.

Comment: @jmaghuyop you aren't converting the database time to UTC in the report output. You can do this using the DateTime.ToUniversalTime method. You could also change the SQL server setting to UTC by default.

Comment: @jmaghuyop if you plan on sticking with UTC, you should change your DB defaults to UTC. That way you don't have to do any formatting on inserting or selecting.

Comment: I think it is working now, what I did was only change the backend code to TransactionDate.ToLocalTime() in C# and dates are now showing the correct date and time.

Is there any other issue that you  can think of if I use ToLocalTime in c#?